# Use Checkbox to auto input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am using google spreadsheet for a project. While making, I have faced a difficulty of not knowing how to code the following behavior:

When a checkbox is checked, input the data on the specific row automatically.

To give an example, if I check the checkbox on cell A20 I want data in B20, C20, D20 to auto input into cell C9, C11 and C13.

I believe this is a simple code but I am not quite familiar with this language... Any help?

Comment: From `To give an example, if I check the checkbox on cell A20 I want data in B20, C20, D20 to auto input into cell C9, C11 and C13.`, in your goal, you want to use only the cells A20, B20, C20, D20, C9, C11 and C13?

Comment: No. That was an example. I will have checkboxes in A20:A and data will be in all B20:D. But data being inputted will be C9, C11 and C13

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `not working`, I think that the reason for your issue is due to both `I have other onEdit(e) functions running and that may be the problem for it to not work.` and the situation of your question is different from your actual situation. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful. Because your question is different from your actual situation. So, I have to delete my answer. Because my answer is to your question and I cannot know your actual situation. I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your actual situation.

Comment: Nono it was helpful thank you. Though I think if you take a look at my spreadsheet, you'll understand how to do it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual goal. So, unfortunately, I cannot think of a solution. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. But, I think that my proposed script can be used to your this question, although my proposed script was not useful for your actual situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 19 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    ["C9", "C11", "C13"].forEach((r, i) => sh.getRange(r).setValue(e.range.offset(0,i + 1).getValue()));
  } 
}
```